# Partial view with in a partial view not displaying Map

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, bing-maps

I had a Partial view that makes an ajax call to get content from other partial view. I am able to view the raw data but unable to load the map content. I think ajax is loading faster than the maps so the the map is not showing up.Please find me an answer!!!

```
               $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("Detail", "Location")',
                    datatype:"html",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#loc').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('AJAX Failure!');
                    }
                });
```

I had controller that loads the partial view

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Detail()
    {
       return PartialView("_Details", ViewModel);
    }
```

In the partial view i had a microsoft map and some raw text.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
     var map = null; 
     var infobox = null;        

     function GetMap()
     {
        // Initialize the map
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"),
                     {credentials:"Bing Maps Key"}); 

        // Retrieve the location of the map center 
        var center = map.getCenter();

        // Create a pin at the center of the map and its corresponding   infobox
        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(center); 
        infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(center, {title: 'Pushpin infobox', visible:false, offset:new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0,35)});

        // Add event handlers for hovering over the pushpin
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'mouseover', showInfobox);
        Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'mouseout', hideInfobox);

        // Add the pushpin and hidden infobox to the map
        map.entities.push(pin);
        map.entities.push(infobox);

     }

     function showInfobox()
     {
        infobox.setOptions({visible:true});

     }

     function hideInfobox()
     {
        infobox.setOptions({visible:false});

     }
     GetMaps();
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: is the myMap div defined? I just cheked out your code and it works just fine

Comment: add width and height to the div which contains map. It should work

Comment: Hi stefan...myMap div is defined....I saw the map once in a while but its hard to render every time.(saw 3 times until now)

Comment: H Nikitesh width and height are already defined in the css for myMap id!

Comment: By "map content" do you mean the map itself or the pushpin+infobox? i.e, do you see an empty map or no map at all?

Comment: No map at all psousa

Comment: i can see the map div but not any map in it